Google Play In-App Updates - is logging in required?
Right now, we are loading multiple Android tablets with the same Google account to our customers, and many customers are complaining that they are constantly being logged out, unable to update our apps to the latest versions.
I know the best way to manage app updates remotely is to use an MDM, but if we implement in-app updates, are they required to log in? I want something as seamless as possible, but I would like to know for sure before I start implementing this. Aurora Store is not an option, since we don't want to risk losing our Google Play Console privileges.

As I wrote in my comment to your last question you should better describe the situation and what you want to do and why. Fir example why do you get away tablets with a pre installed account that doesn't work? If we don't know what problem you want to solve it is difficult to help you. So please edit your question and describe you actual problem. Not the problem that was caused by the way you tried to solve a different problem.

We once tried doing separate accounts for each tablet; Google keeps on asking us for phone SMS verification when setting up each account, so we switched to using a single account for all tablets. However, now our customers are complaining that they keep getting logged out.
